# How to get selected DataGridViewComboBoxColumn values in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, selectedvalue

How to get selected DataGridViewComboBoxColumn values in vb.net?

Answer (score 2):

The first link in my google search :-)

[How to: Access Objects in a Windows Forms DataGridViewComboBoxCell Drop-Down List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404353%28VS.80%29.aspx)

There is a complete example on this MSDN page.

Specifically note the following regarding getting the selected values

> Unlike the ComboBox control, the
>   DataGridView types do not have a
>   SelectedItem  propertyfor retrieving
>   the currently selected object.
>   Instead, you must set the 
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueMember
>   or
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell.ValueMember
>   property to the name  of a property on
>   your business object. When the user
>   makes a selection, the  indicated
>   property of the business object sets
>   the cell Value property.

Click on "VB" in the code boxes to see the appropriate VB.net code syntax